# failed to run custom build command for `wdk-sys v0.2.0`

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

```
PS C:\Users\sleot.LIFERATLER\OneDrive\Desktop\Dawn\work_cargo> cargo check
   Compiling wdk-sys v0.2.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `wdk-sys v0.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\sleot.LIFERATLER\OneDrive\Desktop\Dawn\work_cargo\target\debug\build\wdk-sys-8f6ec34f4eb797b5\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stderr
  Error: cannot find directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km/crt
```

I have windows 11 sdk installed and cmake installed yet I'm still getting this error and I do not know how to solve it. I later on downloaded windows 10 sdk and this was the error

```
**PS C:\Users\sleot.LIFERATLER\OneDrive\Desktop\Dawn\work_cargo> cargo check
   Compiling wdk-sys v0.2.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `wdk-sys v0.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\sleot.LIFERATLER\OneDrive\Desktop\Dawn\work_cargo\target\debug\build\wdk-sys-8f6ec34f4eb797b5\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stderr
# Error: cannot find directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.20348.0\km/crt**
```

Note: All of this were downloaded via visual studio.

Comment: You need to [download the Windows Driver Kit (WDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk).